# Javascript variable checking: (null or undefined) vs boolean

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I want to check in an JS object (example: { x:false, y:true } ) if some properties are either boolean or if they are (null || undefined).

Is there an easy way in JS or Underscore to check this without doing

```
(obj.x != null || obj.x != undefined)
```

???

Comment: `!= null` will check for both. Also I guess you want something like `_.isEmpty`

Comment: != null could be my answer. The _.isEmpty() unfortunately is not what I'm looking, because I'm checking for the conditions separatedly and specifically in some points of my code.

Comment: @Rajesh You should post your own answer with this and I will accept it. I will finally go with _.isBoolean(), but only because it's more readable. For the people in stackoverflow.com reading this, I think the "!= null" answer you gave is the best.

Comment: Thanks. I'm glad I was able to help you. Also its fine. If I had anything substantial, I would have answered already. You can choose any answer that suits the best and accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found an easy way in Underscore:

```
_.isBoolean(obj.x)
```

[Thanks to Rajesh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44429888/javascript-variable-checking-null-or-undefined-vs-boolean#comment75857581_44429888) I know now that `obj.x != null` returns the same if x is null or undefined.

I prefer the Underscore function because it's readable, but the null comparison is native JS and seems more efficient, and simpler.

Answer (score 4):

You could use just the standard [`typeof`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof) operator, which returns `'boolean'` if boolean.

```js
console.log(typeof undefined === 'boolean'); // false
console.log(typeof null === 'boolean');      // false
console.log(typeof true === 'boolean');      // true
console.log(typeof false === 'boolean');     // true
```

Comment: This was good, but I liked best the Underscore function. For native JS this was a good solution. :-)

Answer (score 2):

The `typeof` operator can return whether it is `boolean` or anything else

Reference [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof)

Answer (score 0):

Try this Hope it will help you,

JavaScript

```
function test(v) {
        let type = typeof v;
        if(type === 'undefined') {
            return true;
        }
        if(type=== 'boolean') {
            return false;
        }
        if(v === null) {
            return true;
        }
        if(v === undefined) {
            return true;
        }
        if(v instanceof Array) {
            if(v.length < 1) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        else if(type === 'string') {
            if(v.length < 1) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        else if(type === 'object') {
            if(Object.keys(v).length < 1) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        else if(type === 'number') {
            if(isNaN(v)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: Do we really need `v === undefined` when you have already checked `(type === 'undefined')`? Also you can just check `typeof(c) === "object" && Object.keys(v) === 0`

Comment: You can also refer to [this](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/145413/function-that-checks-for-truth-value)

Comment: How about shortening *(and simplifying)* it to this: `function isEmpty(v){ var type = typeof v; return v == null || type === "string" && !v.length || type === "number" && isNaN(v) || type === "object" && Array.isArray(v)? !v.length: !Object.keys(v).length }`

Answer (score -1):

In Javascript, undefined is evaluated as false, so you should be able to do

```
if (obj.x) {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: `obj.x` will fail for `false` or `0` or `""`